# Android Notification java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications, android-notifications, remoteview

I am writing a music player application on android.App has a custom notification like below.

[image]

In the left part i set album art when song changes. But when i click the next song button more times i get the bad array exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
   at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:677)
```

My code script while setting album art like below.

```
BitMap bitmap = findBitmap("");
notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.albumImage, bitmap);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

public Bitmap findBitmap(String uriStr) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
currentUri = songList.get(currentPosition).getAlbumArtUri();

try {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
            .openFileDescriptor(currentUri, "r");

    if (pfd != null) {
        System.out.println("XXX pfd is not null");
        FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
        Rect r = new Rect();
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, r, options);

        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, r, options);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return bitmap;
```

Comment: Can you post the entire crash trace?